# Emptyness check and change visibility

Tags: javascript, html

This is my html:

```
<textarea name="content" rows="10"></textarea>
```

And this is my js.

```
function popup() {
    var textArea=document.getElementsByName('content');
    var popupArea=document.getElementsByClass('popup');
    if (textArea[0].value=="") {
        window.alert("Input");
    }
    else {
        popupArea[0].innerHTML=textArea[0].value;
        popupArea[0].style.display="block";
    }
}
```

What I want is to make "popup" class contain the text from textarea and be visible, except for textarea is empty: I want to make an alert if it is empty.

It does not work, please help.. As this is a kind of assignment, please avoid suggesting jQuery.

Comment: Ok. And what's your question? You appear to already have code that solves it.

Comment: Please do some debugging on your own. If you open the browser's developer console, you'll see errors. Read them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `getElementsByClass` to `getElementsByClassName`

```js
function popup() {
    var textArea=document.getElementsByName('content');
    var popupArea=document.getElementsByClassName('popup');
    if (textArea[0].value=="") {
        window.alert("Input");
    }
    else {
        popupArea[0].innerHTML=textArea[0].value;
        popupArea[0].style.display="block";
    }
}

popup();
```

```html
<textarea name="content" rows="10"></textarea>
 <div class="popup"></div>
```